# how to find out the centre of the box collider in unity3d?

Tags: triggers, rotation, unity-game-engine

Hi iam trying to build a game in which if i swipe on the device then the player should turn 90 degrees after entering the near by collider. i want the turn to happen only at the centre of the box collider. right now the player is turning when the trigger is entered.. please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the center of the collider by this:

```
Vector3 center = collider.center;
```

and there is a suggestion to implement what you want:

1. Detect Collider.OnTriggerStay(), once this event is received, begin to record players input.
2. Detect Collider.OnTriggerExit(), once this event is received, stop recording players input, and if the player swiped the screen, turn your actor.
3. Reposition your trigger.

And below is some psuedo code:

```
bool shouldTurn = false;

void OnTriggerStay()
{
    if (true//player swiped)
    {
        shouldTurn = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit()
{
    if (shouldTurn)
        //turn your actor

    shouldTurn = false;
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your helping hand.. i have got one more doubt here.. if the swipe is made whenever before near by collider with the trigger stay i want the player to turn only at the center of the collider..

Comment: I think you can just move your collider a little bit, I guess your player should turn at some point based on your scene, not based on your collider, so you can just move your collider to cooperate with your scene to make your player turn at the right point.